# How to properly use the function.php custom_rewrite_rule()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and I have added this function to the functions.php in my theme (the basic twentyone):

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^profile/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=104&name=$matches[1]&age=$matches[2]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules(); // Flush rewrite rules to test the changes immediately
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');

function display_profile_content() {
    $name = sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('name'));
    $age = intval(get_query_var('age'));

    echo 'Name: ' . $name . '<br>';
    echo 'Age: ' . $age . '<br>';
}
add_shortcode('profile_content', 'display_profile_content');

</code>
```

In the specific page I added correctly the shortcode and my intent would be that for example if go to

Website.com/page/Poul/21

It should show:

> Name: Poul
> Age: 21

but whatever I put in the URL it always display:

> Name: profile
> Age:0

Troubleshooting so far:

I have saved the permalink page to flush the cache.
Disabled all plugins
changed theme to this basic one,
but nothing seems to work.

How can I do?

Comment: Just a note: In production, you probably don't want to be doing `flush_rewrite_rules` in the `init` hook. It'll have a performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

The WP_Query does not allow any url parameters, it has list of whitelisted parameters, you can change those parameters using the hook `query_vars`.

Link to [query_vars](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/)

Now in order to make it Work like this.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^profile\/([^/]+)\/(\d+)\/?', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&age=$matches[2]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules(); // Flush rewrite rules to test the changes immediately
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');

add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'age';
    return $query_vars;
} );
function display_profile_content() {
    global $wp_query;
    $name = sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('name'));
    $age = intval(get_query_var('age'));
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $wp_query );
    echo '</pre>';

    echo 'Name: ' . $name . '<br>';
    echo 'Age: ' . $age . '<br>';
}
add_shortcode('profile_content', 'display_profile_content');
```

Also you might have misunderstood your regex, so rewrite_rules takes the profiles/{name}/{age}

so your URL, that works would be `Website.com/profile/Poul/21`

You can test this out in the index.php of your theme by adding this code.

```
do_shortcode('[profile_content]');
```